# JSON undefined result

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following script and it has an interesting interaction.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.get('data/experiments.json', function (data) {
                trialsData = data.experiments;
                console.log(trialsData);
                console.log(data);
                currentTrial = 0;
                totalNumberOfTrials = data.experiments.length;
                $('.js-expt-num-trials').text(totalNumberOfTrials);
                data.experiments.push(headers);
                next();
                pid = ACPToolKit.getCurrentParticipantId();
            })
        });
```

When I `console.log(data)`, it returns the actual and correct data which is

```
{
    "experiments": [
        { 
            "technique": "AUTOCOMPASTE", 
            "granularity": "sentence",
            "data_file": "data/texts.json",
            "stimuli": "What is acceptor atoms?" 
        },
        { 
            "technique": "AUTOCOMPASTE", 
            "granularity": "paragraph",
            "data_file": "data/texts.json",
            "stimuli": "What is AC coupling? Circuit that passes an AC signal while blocking a DC voltage." 
        },
        { 
            "technique": "AUTOCOMPASTE", 
            "granularity": "phrase",
            "data_file": "data/texts.json",
            "stimuli": "number of positive charges" 
        },
        { 
            "technique": "TRADITIONAL", 
            "granularity": "sentence",
            "data_file": "data/texts.json",
            "stimuli": "What is acceptor atoms?" 
        },
        { 
            "technique": "TRADITIONAL", 
            "granularity": "paragraph",
            "data_file": "data/texts.json",
            "stimuli": "What is AC coupling? Circuit that passes an AC signal while blocking a DC voltage." 
        },
        { 
            "technique": "TRADITIONAL", 
            "granularity": "phrase",
            "data_file": "data/texts.json",
            "stimuli": "number of positive charges" 
        }        
    ]
}
```

However, when I `console.log(trialsData)` or even `console.log(data.experiments)` for that matter, it returns undefined. Needless to say that `data.experiments.length` or `trialsData.length` also returns the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I'm pretty sure that `data.experiments` is correct syntax

Comment: Do you need to `JSON.parse` it before you try to access a property?

Comment: Can you try `console.log(data.technique)`

Comment: If you really are getting `{"foo": ...., ....}` in the console, then `data` is a **string**, not an object.

Comment: @AzoulayJason it also returns undefined.

Comment: You are trying to read properties of a `JSON` object, and not a `Javascript` object. Use `JSON.parse` to convert JSON to a Javascript object.

Comment: First try `console.log(Object.keys(data))` - It should show you what properties `data` actually contains. Also try `console.log(typeof(data))` as it will show you what `data` actually is.

Comment: @Thebluefish `console.log(typeof(data))` returns string

Comment: try `trialsData=JSON.parse(data.experiments)`

Comment: @FelixKling thanks that's spot on

Comment: @CHEWWWWWWWWWW those are going to be great troubleshooting steps going forward, FYI.

Comment: maybe:
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data["experiments"]);